# Alter table em tabela gigante

Tags: sql, sql-server

Preciso executar uma operação alter table em vários campos de uma tabela e essa tabela tem mais de um bilhão de linhas. Um operacao para cada campo leva aproximadamente 2 horas e agora imagina para vários campos.

Em ambiente de desenvolvimento executava uma operação para cada campo por vez e agora para executar um script que irá afetar todos os campos de uma vez em Produção vai demorar mais de 15 horas, segundo minha estimativa.

Existe uma forma de otimizar para rodar script mais rápido?

Esse trabalho é justamente para reduzir o tamanho da tabela que tá ficando insuportável.

Comment: Qual o sgbd que vc usa?

Comment: sql server 2012

Comment: Você pode usar o NOVALIDATE no ALTER TABLE que ele não irá validar nada e com isso a instrução executará mais rápido. [Link Util](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa977261(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Penso em algo como: Criar outra tabela com mesma estrutura, fazer o alter table sem ter nenhum dado na tabela, inserir os registros nesta tabela e renomear com o nome da original.

Comment: @Everson, como eu usaria? no caso desse exemplo aqui:

ALTER TABLE TABELA
ALTER COLUMN VALOR numeric(22,10)

Comment: No Management Studio, a edição de tabela via _object explorer_ cria o script para fazer exatamente como o @DiegoSchmidt disse. Pegue o script e edite conforme a necessidade.